# Windows Server 2008 Sleep at night

Tags: windows-server-2008, sleep, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, windows-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 home server, that i'm going to sleep during the night. It's BIOS does not support scheduled boot. Can i use some kind of task in the Scheduled Tasks to make it sleep at 10PM and wake it again at 8AM in the morning?

Comment: Don't think so. Either it supports scheduled boot or it doesn't. You could try some Wake-on-LAN shenanigans but I wouldn't want to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you **can't find** an option of scheduled boot in the BIOS does not mean it does not support it.

If your computer supports [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) (all modern ones do) you should be able to schedule a boot via the OS.
I'd recommend taking a look at the free [WakeupOnStandby](http://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/).

You say `It's BIOS does not support scheduled boot`. If you mean by that it does **not** have ACPI ([Advanced Configuration and Power Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)) hardware support then there is no way to make a schedule boot (other than the WakeupOnLan Tanner suggested).

Well... there is always the way of putting a timer on the power-cable :)